# $regex in mongodb pipeline

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, aggregate

I want to be able to use $regex to be able to find any words that contain certain keyword given by user, but it is not working. I have this:

```
aggregatePipeline.push({
      $match: {
        name: {
          $regex: `/${name.toLowerCase()}/`,
        },
      },
    });
```

I tried using $regexMatch, but it says it is not supported for free tier. Is there a work around?

```
{
      $regexMatch: {
        input: "$name",
        regex: `/${name}/`,
      },
}
```

I'm trying to avoid $regexMatch at least for now due to free tier.

I am able to retrieve user by the exact name, but I also want to retreive all names that have a substring ex. 'ger', should retrieve 'Gerry', 'Gerald', 'anger'....

```
aggregatePipeline.push({ $match: { name: name.toLowercase() } });
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

{ 'search field': { $regex: new RegExp('search name', 'gi') } }

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you, I found out I could use $match: { name: { $regex: `.*${name.toLowerCase()}.*` } }  , also using your approach I would need to add $match which code will end up like this:  $match: {
        name: {
          $regex: new RegExp(`${name.toLowerCase()}`, "gi"),
        },
      }